# Display month name in DatePicker

Tags: android

In my app I am using calendar view of DatePicker, but it doesn't display name of current month. I think it is not very convenient for user. Is there a way to display month name?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
public static final String[] MONTHS = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
String mon=MONTHS[monthNumber];
```

and use the `mon`

Comment: also you can use this answer to build your own month picker

Comment: So you suggest just to use TextView and show new month's name when date is being changed?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
DatePicker datepicker=new DatePicker();
int month=date.getMonth();
public static final String[] MONTHS = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
String mon=MONTHS[month];
```

Hope this helps!